# Moving from Azure for Students to Pay as you go

Tags: azure, azureportal

I made web app for contest and I was using "Azure for Students" subscription for it. But I lost all of my free credits so I decided to move to "Pay as you go" subscription plan but I don't know how.

[image: App service]

And when I trying to change subscription I getting message like this:

> Can't move resources from disabled subscription

I used 129$ / 100$ from my Student's subscription and I can't enable it.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: You need to contact Azure support

Comment: Or just wait till you get new credits and then move resources to another subscription.

Comment: How did you lose your credits?

Comment: Having like 2 vm's working 24/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Azure for Students FAQ](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/free/free-account-students-faq/), to continue using Azure after you exhaust your available credits, you may upgrade to a [Pay-As-You-Go subscription](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/offers/ms-azr-0003p/) by contacting [Azure Support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/options/). After you upgrade, you pay only for services you use over the free quantity included.

After you exhaust your available credit or reach the end of 12 months, your Azure subscription will be disabled. If you've reached the end of your 12 months and are still a student, you'll be able to renew your Azure for Students offer. You will be notified shortly before your 12-month period to let you know how to renew. If you are no longer a student, you may choose to upgrade to a Pay-As-You-Go subscription.

If you decide not to upgrade at the end of 12 months or after you have exhausted your 100 USD credit, whichever occurs first, any products you have deployed will be decommissioned and you will not be able to access them.

However, you can always [export your resource definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal) in the form of [Azure Resource Manager templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/overview) (ARM templates) to be reused later. Just like application code, you can store the infrastructure code in a source repository and version it. Any one on your team can run the code and deploy similar environments.